# Samsung Galaxy J1 will not play music from my SD card

Tags: samsung, external-sd, music

I have purchased a Samsung Galaxy J1 and it will not read any of my music from my SD card. My photos show up but no music. SD card worked okay in the last phone.

I have tried to download music players and MP3 conversions but nothing works. Staff at Spark said that they have no idea what to do.

Please help.

Comment: Create a folder named **Music** in your _SD Card_ and move all songs to that folder. Try if that works

Comment: In my case I had disabled the *Google Play Music* app, so no music was playable; neither from the SD card nor from internal storage. Not exactly the same issue, but just in case someone else hits this :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the songs to your SD card, while connecting your mobile to the PC and try to play these songs. Also try using TTPod music player as the inbuilt Samsung music player won't support the different formats.

Comment: Thanks already tried this and it did not work. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be the file format of my music which is not supported on the Samsung Galaxy J1.

I installed the [PowerAmp app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer) from the Play Store and I can now play my music. PowerAmp plays just about every type of music file. There is a trial version which lasts two weeks so you can test to see if it works for you. The [full version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer.unlock) costs £2.99 when you are satisfied that it works, and want to buy the full app.